# Volume mixing Windows 8 Metro apps

Tags: windows-8, audio, windows-store-app, volume-mixer

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I control the audio volume of a Modern-UI application?](https://superuser.com/questions/506753/how-can-i-control-the-audio-volume-of-a-modern-ui-application)

In Windows 7, you could volume mix programs, using the built in volume mixer:

[image: volume mixer]

In windows 8, you can access the mixer in exactly the same way as in 7, on the desktop, but from here you can only mix desktop apps.

However, I cannot find a way of volume mixing Metro apps.

How can I volume mix Windows 8 Metro apps?

Comment: You might be able to find a replacement application on the Windows Store I am sure something like this is possible its just a design choice by Microsoft for the Volume Mixer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

from what I now, this is not possible:

[Link](https://web.archive.org/web/20151018073501/http://blogs.msdn.com/b/windowsappdev/archive/2012/08/23/media-playback-what-you-need-to-know-about-playing-media-to-make-your-app-shine-in-windows-8.aspx)

> **There is no audio mixer in this environment as there is in the desktop.** It still exists for desktop applications, but your app won’t show up here because we felt it was not a great experience to pop out into desktop to adjust relative app volumes. Instead, we are encouraging apps to not include volume controls. This way users are focused on the master volume control which helps simplify the entire volume experience as well – but that’s a different story.