# Does ClassicShell.net truly lets one boot to the desktop on Windows 8?

Tags: windows-8, boot, desktop

Many people complain about the start screen of Windows 8, especially people used to desktop PCs, rather than tablets. I have read contradictory comments about ClassicShell letting one boot to the desktop. Does it really let one boot directly to a Windows 7 look-alike desktop rather than the typical Windows 8 'touch' screen?

P.S.: I don't have a PC with Windows 8 installed, otherwise, I would have tried it myself.

Comment: Do you mean specifically the ClassicShell add-on? If so, it may help to include a link to http://www.classicshell.net/ in your question to reduce confusion.

Comment: This doesn't seem like a real problem you face. You have not even tried it in a virtual machine.

Comment: last I was aware, MS had not said for certain exactly what will be in 8.1. also, the issue is not what a user "is used to", but what a user user "is using". why would anyone use metro on a pair of 27"s without touch capacity, running at 1080p? I'm set up for lots of screen real-estate, and the ability to pack things in rather densely for dev work. at that resolution and dimension, the size of someones finger print on a tablet is like 5" square on my rig.

Comment: @FrankThomas: By now there aren't any Win8.1 surprises given the official announcements: [1](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VQb5caeSo00) [2](http://blogs.windows.com/windows/b/business/archive/2013/06/03/modern-business-in-mind-windows-8-1-at-teched-2013.aspx) [3](http://blogs.windows.com/windows/b/springboard/archive/2013/06/03/what-s-new-for-the-enterprise-in-windows-8-1.aspx) [4](http://i.stack.imgur.com/1JU9F.jpg) (fixed broken YT link).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To answer your question, yes the **Skip Metro screen**  option of [**Classic Shell**](http://www.classicshell.net) works as advertised:

[image: 1]

BTW, nothing much has changed about the desktop in Win8 (it's not a "look-alike desktop") except for the loss of the Start button and the Start Menu being replaced by the Start Screen. Even Windows/File Explorer (which you seem to be concerned about as per your other question) is pretty much the same; it's just been "ribbonified" like Office was.

A "fake" Start button will reappear in the free Windows 8.1 Update/Service Pack later this year (it will simply take you to the Start Screen), and Boot to Desktop will be an officially supported feature so there'll no longer be a need to use 3rd party apps just for this.

Comment: I think JVerstry is specifically talking about http://www.classicshell.net/

Comment: @rob: Right, and what did you think I posted a screenshot of? :) (Don't go by the window title, that's what it is in the program. Focus on the window icon instead.)

Comment: Thanks for the clarification; the window title is what threw me off.

Comment: @rob: NP, I knew you were trying to help and thought I might have misunderstood the OP and started discussing some other program altogether.

Comment: @Karan I have set the setting as your snapshot but the start button does not showed; i.e. have to start Classic Shell once at start up.

Comment: @NamG.VU: As I mentioned in response to your previous comment on the other question, unfortunately this isn't something I can really debug. If a reinstall doesn't fix this, I again advise you to post on the CS forum for best results.

Comment: OK @Karan. Thanks a lot! I'll post the forum then.

Answer (score 2):

WinKey + D will give you the desktop (like windows 7 has) from the start screen of Windows 8.

Comment: I know "Soluto" will do it as well as Stardock "Start8".

Comment: This is true but fails to answer the question.

Comment: I think JVerstry is specifically talking about http://www.classicshell.net/

Comment: Yes, I am talking about classicshell.net